# Having issues with new JSonUtitilty/JSonHelper in Unity, returning null when it should be a class

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, loading

I created the JSonHelper class by following along here:
http://www.boxheadproductions.com.au/deserializing-top-level-arrays-in-json-with-unity/

and have a json file as follows:

```
{"Items":[{"id":0,"name":"player","baseStats":[10,0,0,0,0,0],"xpyield":0,"evyield":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"moves":["Ember","","",""],"health":0,"stats":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"evs":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"level":1,"xp":0},{"id":1,"name":"frosline","baseStats":[10,0,0,0,0,0],"xpyield":0,"evyield":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"moves":["Ember","Blast","",""],"health":0,"stats":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"evs":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"level":1,"xp":0}]}
```

Also have a MonsterStats Class:

```
public class MonsterStats
{

public int id;
public string name;
public int[] baseStats;
public int xpyield = 0;//0-4 for each stat
public int[] evyield = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
public string[] moves;

public int health;
public int[] stats;
public int[] evs;
public int level;
public int xp;


}
```

And finally the code where I'm having issues:

```
    jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/Monsters.json");

    monsterData = JsonHelper.FromJson<MonsterStats>(jsonString);
    Debug.Log(monsterData);
```

This Debug.Log returns null, any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Was simply missing [System.Serializable] or whatever before MonsterStats